# Изменение языка для alert

Tags: swift, spritekit

делаю изменение языка, для label делаю так `self.Labl.text = HLLocalizeHelper.localizedString("LOCALIZ_ME", stringFileName:"Local");` 
а как сделать перевод для alert?

```html
  let titleAttributed = NSAttributedString(string: "TITLE", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 22)!])
                alertController.setValue(titleAttributed, forKey: "attributedTitle")
                let messageAttributed = NSAttributedString(string: "Message", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)])
                alertController.setValue(messageAttributed, forKey: "attributedMessage")             alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 90.0, green: 70.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 0.5)              alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
              alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "play", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    self.view?.presentScene(Start(), transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))
                    self.ScoreWin = 10
                    self.downMenuButton.removeFromSuperview()
                }))
```

Comment: у вас в alert есть две строки "Message" и "play" - вместо них выполняйте тот же код, что у вас в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же:

```html
  let titleAttributed = NSAttributedString(string: HLLocalizeHelper.localizedString("TITLE", stringFileName:"Local"), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: HLLocalizeHelper.localizedString("MARKER", stringFileName:"Local"), size: 22)!])
                alertController.setValue(titleAttributed, forKey: "attributedTitle")
                let messageAttributed = NSAttributedString(string: HLLocalizeHelper.localizedString("My_message", stringFileName:"Local"), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)])
                alertController.setValue(messageAttributed, forKey: "attributedMessage")             alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 90.0, green: 70.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 0.5)              alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
              alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: HLLocalizeHelper.localizedString("PLAY", stringFileName:"Local"), style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    self.view?.presentScene(Start(), transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))
                    self.ScoreWin = 10
                    self.downMenuButton.removeFromSuperview()
                }))
```

Не забудьте определить в файле локализации ключи: TITLE, MARKER и т.д.